# Javascript Cookie onload Call

Tags: javascript, cookies, function-calls

I have a cookie that I did using javascript and to check if it had to be replaced I used "onload=checkCookie()" in the body tag of the HTML, however now I'm trying to place the js in another file and just link it using the  tag, but if I do that I can no longer call this function using just "onload" so I was wondering how can I do this? everybody else I've asked tells me to leave the code there, but I want to separate my design in layers =S

here's the js:

```
function getCookie(c_name){
    if (document.cookie.length>0){
        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start!=-1){ 
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1; 
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
            if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        } 
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays){
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+
    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
}

function checkCookie(){
    username=getCookie('username');
    if(username!=null && username!=""){
        alert('Welcome again '+username+'!');
    }else{
        username=prompt('Please enter your name:',"");
        if(username!=null && username!=""){
            setCookie('username',username,365);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is inside a file called init.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the script in a separate file is a good thing.
Add the onload function to the script-

**window**.onload=checkCookie; //(no parenthesis) and take it out of the html.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the issue, you should be able to use the body's onload to execute javascript even if it is from an external file, like this:

This is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="hello()">
</body>
</html>
```

This is the linked javascript:

```
var hello = function()
{
    alert("Hello!");
}
```